# How to check android wifi connection?

Tags: android

I want to check if it is connected to WiFi. If connected, the phone is silent. When the program is running application stopped working

```
 ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                final AudioManager audioManager=
                        (AudioManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

            }
            else
            {
                final AudioManager audioManager=
                        (AudioManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            }
```

Comment: Post stacktrace of error

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: Add your error log

Comment: the question not cleared, where is the stack trace, the issue you want to fix?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use this method if connect then it will return true else false remember it will not work on Emulator please test it on real device .. Thanks

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            //we are connected to a network
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: don't want to explain your answer?

Comment: you can directly use this method if connect then it will return true else false

Comment: downvoting this as you cannot update your code with the above comment